# How to authenticate my github account?

Tags: git, github

I am learning from one tutorial,they show us how to install and create github account.How could I login to my existing account?I am working from Linux shell.
With git config I have come to this

```
git config --global --list
user.email=fabiano.mota@gmail.com
user.name=fabiano.mota@gmail.com
```

This line solves problem

```
curl -i -u FabianoM https://api.github.com/users/defunkt
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What exactly do you want to do when you 'log in'? You can't log in, you can clone a repository, try to fetch / pull / push changes and then it will ask you for authentication (username and password) so you can complete the action.

Comment: Ok,Yes I see now.